# how to use xargs to extract a list of names from IRC

Tags: bash, text-processing, scripting, regular-expression, xargs

[Using](https://superuser.com/q/1663359/977796) the `finch` IRC client, I copy/pasted a list of names to `names.txt` for processing.

Basically, the names are seperated by spaces.  Many of the names will have special characters like "/" or "%" in them.  Apparently.  By "name" here I mean IRC handle, which is, presumably, a single word.

I tried using `xargs` to pull out a "list" of names as `xargs names.txt` but the command just hung.

Can I use `xargs` for this?  If so, how?

---

sample input:

```
word1 word2 word3
```

sample output

```
word1
word2
word3
```

pardon for overcomplicating the question.

Comment: `xargs` either reads from standard input (`xargs < names.txt`) or from a file given as an argument to the `-a` option (`xargs -a names.txt`)

Comment: ah, `xargs < names.txt` echoes out the file but doesn't seperate each word on a new line as was looking for.  Basically, a "list" of all the "words" in the file in a regex way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `xargs` to process at most `num` arguments per call using `-n max-args`

> ```
>    -n max-args, --max-args=max-args
>           Use  at  most  max-args  arguments per command line.  Fewer than
>           max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the -s  option)
>           is  exceeded, unless the -x option is given, in which case xargs
>           will exit.
> ```

So

```
xargs -n 1 < names.txt
```

(arguments are separated by whitespace by default).

However that's somewhat subverting the intent of `xargs` - you might consider using something like `tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' < names.txt` instead.